# Power BI - Average Per Category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am brand new to Power BI, and I could use a bit of help. I have this sample data:

[image]

I then want to get the [Average Total Billed Per Profession], which I got using:

[image]

Then, ideally, I would [Total Billed]/[Average Total Billed Per Profession]. But when I drop it in a table, it breaks. On the left, are the values I would want in the calculation. On the right, the values I get:

[image]

How would I set up the calculation correctly? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: beware, adding columns in SUMMARIZE is deprecated https://dax.guide/summarize/

Answer (score 2):

To have the average per profession in a table where also the Name is present, it's necessary to remove the filter context over Name, so a possible solution is

```
Average Total Bille Per Profession =
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE( StaticData, StaticData[Profession], StaticData[Name] ),
        CALCULATE( SUM( StaticData[Price] ) )
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT( StaticData, StaticData[Profession] )
)
```

The CALCULATE inside AVERAGEX is required to trigger a context transition to transform the row context on the StaticData columns to a the corresponding filter context, that's needed to filer the StaticData[PriceColumn] rows to be used in the SUM.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. Could you tell me why you wrapped the internal SUM in CALCULATE? Is it just best practice?

Comment: Hi, I expanded the answer to explain that CALCULATE inside AVERAGEX is needed to cause the context transition

Answer (score 0):

It looks like profession + name doesn't make each row unique. If you just want "Average Total Billed Per Profession", then you can use something like the following.

```
Average Total Bille Per Profession =

AVERAGEX(
    VALUES( StaticData[Profession] ), 
    SUM( StaticData[Price] )
)
```

It's just making sure you're considering unique profession for the metric you're calculating.